# How to stop an existing spinner

Tags: javascript

I have the following Ajax request which is within a partial view that requests addresses from a service and can take a few seconds to populate the table:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updatearea", OnBegin = "ShowLoading", OnComplete = "HideLoading" }))
{
    <div id="updatearea" class="form-group">

        <div style="width:300px; display:block; float:left;">
            @Html.TextBox("PostCode", null, new { @class = "form-control" })            
        </div>

        <div id="NewAddressLine">

            <input id="btnLookupPostcode" type="submit" value="Lookup Postcode" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="spinner"></div>
}
```

And this JavaScript which is successfully starting the loading spinner but not stopping it once the partial view has rendered fully:

```
function ShowLoading() {
            var opts = {
                lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
                length: 20, // The length of each line
                width: 10, // The line thickness
                radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
                corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
                rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
                direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
                color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
                speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
                className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
                zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
                top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
                left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
            };
            var target = document.getElementById('spinner');
            var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        }

        function HideLoading() {                      
            var spinner = $('.spinner');
            spinner.stop();
        }
```

Please make it stop!

Comment: spinner.remove(). ;-)

Comment: https://github.com/fgnass/spin.js/blob/master/spin.js#L201 Shows stop() should work assuming reference is same instance.

Comment: In `HideLoading()` you are redeclaring `spinner` as a jQuery object. Presumably the `.stop()` method is not bound to this object. Define `spinner` outside of these show/hide methods.

Comment: @Moob The partial view is being injected into a Div when I click a button, this is meaning the JS cannot see anything related to the partial until it has been opened, how can I create the spinner outside the show/hide methods before the partial has been launched, the spinner div is inside the partial?

Comment: @Shikkediel this works, is it the right way to do it though?

Comment: Can always set a var outside of both function scopes and assign to the var from inside the ShowLoading and HideLoading functions.

Comment: I'd probably want to move my configuration object literal outside the scope of your ShowLoading function as well, no sense in recreating that object every time the function is called.

Comment: @SelectDistrict I don't think it's wrong in any way but it'll completely remove the spinner so you won't be able to call upon it again without reloading.

Comment: @Shikkediel change your comment into an answer

Comment: This topic can also answer to your question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054846/show-hide-spinner-on-select-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posted as a comment initially and a bit of a radical solution but this will stop it completely :

```
spinner.remove()
```

Cleans up all references and attached events...

Answer (score 1):

Might be spinner.spin(false) or $('.spin').spin('hide'); depending on jQuery plugin in use. Which library are you using? Just spin.js?

Your reference to the widget may be getting lost as well. Numerous ways to fix this; essentially make a variable in a scope you know will be maintained and assign the widget to that variable for safe keeping.

```
    var MySpinner = function(){

        var spinner = undefined; //Widget will be assigned here

        var opts = {
            lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
            length: 20, // The length of each line
            width: 10, // The line thickness
            radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
            corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
            rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
            direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
            color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
            speed: 1, // Rounds per second
            trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
            zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
            top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
            left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
        };

        return { 
            show: function(){
                var target = document.getElementById('spinner');
                spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
            }, 
            hide: function(){
                spinner.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    var spinnerInstance = new MySpinner();
    spinnerInstance.show();
    spinnerInstance.hide();
```