# Show/hide spinner on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [LoadAwesome](http://github.danielcardoso.net/load-awesome/) and I want to know how can I show spinner div when I change select value before load the data. **Currently I'm using AJAX requests to load the data.**

**Simple explanation:** selected change -> show spinner -> load data

I'll already try to do this, but data is loaded without the spinner effect. :(

```
<select id="select_data">
  <option value="">Choose one..</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
<div class="content">
  <div id="spinner">
    <div style="color: #79bbb5" class="la-ball-spin-fade la-2x">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="text"></div>
</div>

$("#select_data").change(function() {
    // I want to show the spinner when I change select value before load the data -->
   // So before show this, I'll show the spinner and then, the text.
   $("#text").html(($("#select_data option:selected").text()));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0e6rtog5 - Unfortunatel jsfiddle doesn't show the spinner.

Comment: An animated load sphere?

Comment: you are asking me lol?

Answer (score 1):

This will give gist of what you can do to load spinner on select change

```
$("#select_data").on('change', function() {
  // show spinner here
  $('#spinner').show(); // or do addClass('spinner')

  $.ajax({
    url: "test.html"
  }).done(function() {
    // hide again on response of ajax
    $('#spinner').hide(); // or remove class removeClass('spinner')
  });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/e8nxLwta/5/)

Please also add url for `LoadAwesome` module so that its easier for us

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Show on change:

```
 $('.la-ball-spin-fade').hide();//hide by default  -can use css
    $("#select_data").change(function({     
    $('.la-ball-spin-fade').show();
        //trigger ajax
    });
```

hide it at ajax success:

```
...
success:function(data) {
//other data manipulation;
 $('.la-ball-spin-fade').hide();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mgp699za/1/

Comment: I don't want to add spinner class to select but to the content. I updated my code and jsfidlle for you understand better what I want.